# Bluetooth turning on, but cannot scan any device on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, bluetooth

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 a while ago, and have been using my bluetooth headset seamlessly. However, after a recent system update, the bluetooth has gone haywire. It says that it is enabled and visible (can scan and see laptop on other bluetooth devices) but when I try to add a bluetooth device, none of the bluetooth devices show up in the scan.

I've tried restarting the laptop/reinstalling bluez etc, but still the problem persists. 
I would really appreciate if anybody can help me out here.

Thanks a lot!

Athreya

I also presume I have to include this information in the question:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep blue; rfkill list all; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
--
04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:1447]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5710 IMC Networks UVC VGA Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             520192  40 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[    0.282831] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.979268] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    2.228981] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f02)
[   11.866226] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   11.866244] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.866248] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.866250] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.866255] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.674179] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   25.674183] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   25.674187] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   55.996025] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   55.996033] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   55.996037] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: I hate to ask this but did you put the other devices in pairing(discoverable) mode before scanning with the Ubuntu computer?

Comment: Of course! I've tried it all! I'm not really technologically challenged you know.. ;-)

Comment: Try `bluetoothctl` then `power on` and with a device discoverable use `scan on` to see if it works that way.  Sorry about that question but it wouldn't be the first time

Comment: Hey! That helped! It works now! Thanks a ton! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is to open terminal and then enter

```
bluetoothctl
```

This opens the bluetooth control in terminal, then enter the command to power the bluetooth device with

```
power on
```

And finally turn scanning on

```
scan on
```

If more commands are needed type `help`